# How to resolve IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(
    [
        [-1.54,  4.82,  1.99,  1.96, -1.3,   2.41, 36.28],
        [1.67,  4.41,  1.62,  1.87,  6.7,   2.43, 34.91],
        [-1.4,   4.41,  1.68,  1.91,  4.15,  2.51, 40.44]
    ]
)

score = np.array(
    [
        [0.68],
        [0.61],
        [0.42],
    ]
)

score_threshold = 0.5

result = data[score > score_threshold, :]
```

**The result should be:**

```
[-1.54,  4.82,  1.99,  1.96, -1.3,   2.41, 36.28],
[1.67,  4.41,  1.62,  1.87,  6.7,   2.43, 34.91]
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Core/sup.py", line 21, in <module>
    result = data[score > score_threshold, :]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

*I will be very glad if someone can help!!!*
And if it is possible to get exactly the same result without using a *numpy*, but only *lists*, it will be very cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
result = data[score[:,0] > score_threshold]
```

Alternatively this works (by changing your data layout):

```
score = np.array(
    [
        0.68,  # Note, not nested.
        0.61,
        0.42,
    ]
)

result = data[score > score_threshold]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
data[np.where(np.any(score > score_threshold, axis=1))]
```